# Issues trying to execute Form Class in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Good evening.
I have a problem using NetBeans v 11.1 for Windows.
I try to open two Frame Forms when the user select an item from a Combo Box.
The forms I want open have a string param in their constructors.

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Visualizza visualizza = new Visualizza(this.auth);
        Inserisci inserisci = new Inserisci(this.auth);
        var getItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

        switch(getItem.toString()){
            case ("Visualizza Iscritti nel Sistema"):

                visualizza.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case ("Inserisci Atleti nel Sistema"):
                inserisci.setVisible(true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Select.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

The constructors code is:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import org.json.*;

    public class Visualizza extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //Attributes declaration 
     ...
    public Visualizza(String auth) throws IOException {
    initComponents();
    btnRicerca.setVisible(false);
    txtField.setVisible(false);
    this.auth = auth;


    Player[] player; 
    Requests r = new Requests("https://www.kingofthecage.it/API/getAllPlayers.php", auth);
    r.sendGet();
    if (r.res.equals("Errore") || r.res.equals("[]"))
    {
        List.removeAll();
        List.add(errorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(r.res);
        player = new Player[arr.length()];
        String[] list = new String[arr.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
        {
            String id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID");
            String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOME");
            String surname = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("COGNOME");
            String date = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("DATA_NASCITA");
            String birthplace = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("LUOGO_NASCITA");
            String residence = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("RESIDENZA");
            String cf = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("CODICE_FISCALE");
            String mail = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("MAIL");
            String mobile = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("CELLULARE");
            String team = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOME_SQUADRA");
            player[i] = new Player(id, name, surname, date, birthplace, residence, cf, mobile, mail, team);

            List.add(list[i] = player[i].getPlayerString());

        }


    }
```

I import the library org.json to parse and interact with a response from a server, called with an HTTP Request and in the for cycle I returned params in a class called Player.

If I run the project from NetBeans works perfectly, the issue come when I build the project and I try to execute the .jar file saved in "./dist" folder. Substantially when I select a value from the ComboBox nothing happens but, as i've said, if I try to run the same code in NetBeans IDE it works.

I specify that I never change any setting from NetBeans IDE.
I hope you can solve my problem!

Comment: 1. Any exceptions showing up in your log file?  2. Time to do some debugging. You may need to break your code up into testable units and test each section, even in its own jar file if need be. Separate the GUI concerns from the I/O concerns. 3. Are you trying to access resources held within the jar file as if they were Files?

Comment: re "I import the library org.json" -- does your jar's manifest file have the correct class-path to this library?

Comment: I now add an empty Frame and i opened it as I do with the other, calling the method "setVisible" from another Frame. The empty frame  is opened correctly. I think the issue is caused by the importing of the library org.json. It's stored in a folder called Project/lib and the built .jar file is going to store in another folder called Project/dist.
I've this doubts because I used Eclipse for a long time and with it the library files was built automatically in the executable .jar file

Comment: Please answer my specific questions

Comment: No exceptions. I now import the org.json library in the empty Frame and test the code to add in the class Player the attributes. I have the issue another time. So the problem is with the import I think. About your last question I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: *****SOLVED*****

I simple import the file into the library .jar file inside the built project .jar file. Tahnks to all for the help!